# how do I trim an email input address so only the data before the @ is inputted into the database?

Tags: mysql, forms, coldfusion, trim, email-address

I am using coldfusion 9 to add data into a MySQL database from a form.

I would like to create a username from the email address inputed into the form.

for example,

```
<cfset store_user_email = EMAILADDRESS>
<cfset store_username = trim EMAILADDRESS before the @>
```

I'm not sure how to trim down the email address?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have 5 questions and have not accepted a single answer.  I suggest you start marking some of them or the free help will dry up.  FYI- I haven't answered any of them that I know of, so I don't have a dog in the hunt, I'm just letting you know.

Answer (score 8):

```
<cfset store_username = trim(listFirst(EMAILADDRESS,"@"))>
```

Comment: The List functions are very powerful if you can get your head around a string as a list.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response, that has worked a treat.